# What happens when getting ERROR: role "foo" does not exist with psql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm importing a database with:

```
sudo -u postgres psql mydb < mydb.bak
```

And I get the following error in the console many times:

> ERROR:  role "foo" does not exist

I'm wondering what happens in such case. Is it using another user, and if yes, which one ? The database owner or maybe just postgres ?

Comment: Use the `-U` option of `psql` to specify the desired database user.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I get `FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "dev"` when using `sudo -u postgres psql -U dev mydb < mydb.bak`

Comment: Then change `pg_hba.conf` appropriately and reload.

Comment: if you enable non-peer logins in `pg_hba.conf` (e.g. via password). then you don't don't need sudo at all, and can use `psql -U dev mydb` directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your `mydb.bak` is coming from another Postgres cluster/instance where there is a role `foo`. I'm also going to guess the cluster you are importing into does not have that role. In that case you may have objects that have privileges assigned to role `foo` and no such role in the new database. Then you get the errors you are seeing.  If that is the case then you will either need to add it manually to the new cluster/instance or use `pg_dumpall -g` on the other instance to get the global objects, which includes roles. Be aware this will include all global's so you may not want that.